# SQL Query returns two columns but DataSet only contains one and says the other does not exist

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have the following code executing a stored procedure and returning the results to fill a dropdownlist.

```
private DataSet GetData(string SPName, SqlParameter SPParameter)
{
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HMT2DBCS"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SPName, con);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (SPParameter != null)
            {
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(SPParameter);
            }

            con.Open();

            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(DS);

            con.Close();

            return DS;
        }
}

public void PopulateTicket()
{
        DataSet DS = GetData("spGetTickets", null);
        ddlTicket.DataSource = DS;
        ddlTicket.DataTextField = "TicketInfo";
        ddlTicket.DataValueField = "MicroBT_ticket";
        ddlTicket.DataBind();

        ListItem liticket = new ListItem("--Select a ticket--", "-1");
        ddlTicket.Items.Insert(0, liticket);
}
```

When this executes I get this error:

> System.Web.HttpException: 'DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'TicketInfo'.'

When I run the stored procedure from SSMS I get the following results table, which does contain the column `TicketInfo`:

[image: Database Query Results]

I have double checked spelling of all the columns and fields. I have a duplicate copy of the VS project and a duplicate 'test' database setup on another PC and the same code works fine there! I have no idea what could be throwing this error.

**UPDATE**: DataSet visualizer shows the following in my DataSet, the `TicketInfo` column is missing for some reason:

[image: Data Visualizer]

Comment: I would encourage you to use an ORM like the Entity Framework. Makes working with datasets so much easier.

Comment: Just above the line: "return DS;",  can you run some code like: DS.WriteXml(@"c:\temp\result.xml", System.Data.XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema); 
This will write the contents of the dataset to a file. If you paste the contents in the xml file to your post, we can see easier what is going on. You'll have to create the directory  c:\temp   beforehand if it doesn't exist (or use another directory your app has write permission to).

Comment: ... of course, don't post any sensitive info from the file - you can replace sensitive parts with XXX or something.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to work with is a [`DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netcore-3.1) not `DataSet`, so your code should be like this:

```
DataTable DT = GetData("spGetTickets", null).Tables[0];
ddlTicket.DataSource = DT;
```

Answer (score 1):

About the ORM I mentioned in my comment. Here's an example on how to define a class for the Entity Framework (code first) which you can reverse engineer from the database tables very easily. The Entity Framework does that for you.

Below that is an example I posted earlier for another question on this Forum. You can see how easy it is to retrieve data from a table in the DB using LINQ and there's lots more you can do.

```
namespace ToPagedList
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    [Table("Course")]
    public partial class Course
    {
        public int CourseId { get; set; }

        public int? CourseGroupId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string CourseCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        [Required]
        public string Contents { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string MailTextApplied { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string MailTextAccepted { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string MailTextRejected { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string MailTextDeleted { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string ExternalRegistrationUrl { get; set; }

        public bool Visible { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string ExternalCourseUrl { get; set; }

        public string Reviews { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string School { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string MailTextCertified { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string MailTextNoShow { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string MailTextPassed { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string MailTextPartlyCompleted { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string MailTextWaitingList { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string MailTextWithdrawn { get; set; }

        public bool ShowFromStartDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's the code for retrieving data:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ToPagedList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            sw.Start();

            var list1 = Repository.GetCourses1();

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Getting list 1 took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds");


            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();

            var list2 = Repository.GetCourses2();

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Getting list 2 took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Repository class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ToPagedList
{
    public class Repository
    {
        public static List<DocumentsModel> GetCourses1(string school = null, string code = null, string title = null, int page = 0, int count = 15)
        {
            var courses = new DocumentModelEntities().Course;

            return courses.Where(course => string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) || course.CourseCode.Contains(code))
                                 .Where(course => String.IsNullOrEmpty(title) || course.Title.Contains(title))
                                 .Where(w => String.IsNullOrEmpty(school) || w.School == school)
                                 // From here your table is read from the DB using the where clauses
                                 .Select(s => new DocumentsModel
                                 {
                                     Code = code.Trim(),
                                     Title = s.Title
                                 })
                                 .OrderBy(o => o.Code)
                                 .Skip(page * count)
                                 .Take(count)
                                 .ToList();
        }

        public static List<DocumentsModel> GetCourses2(string school = null, string code = null, string title = null, int page = 0, int count = 15)
        {
            var courses = new DocumentModelEntities().Course;

            return courses.Where(course => string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) || course.CourseCode.Contains(code))
                             .Where(course => String.IsNullOrEmpty(title) || course.Title.Contains(title))
                             .Where(w => String.IsNullOrEmpty(school) || w.School == school)
                             .OrderBy(course => course.CourseCode)
                             .Skip(page * count)
                             .Take(count)
                             // From here your table is read from the DB using the where clauses, order by, skip and take
                             .Select(s => new DocumentsModel
                             {
                                 Code = code.Trim(),
                                 Title = s.Title
                             })
                             .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```